# Restructure an array of events in PHP combining attendees with common location

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array that holds the dates, locations and time a person will be attending an event. It starts in this format (The original array is always delivered in date/time order):

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(8) "1st June"
    ["events"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["location"]=>
        string(7) "Venue A"
        ["name"]=>
        string(4) "Pete"
        ["time"]=>
        string(6) "4.00pm"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["location"]=>
        string(7) "Venue A"
        ["name"]=>
        string(4) "John"
        ["time"]=>
        string(6) "4.30pm"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
        ["location"]=>
        string(7) "Venue B"
        ["name"]=>
        string(5) "Chris"
        ["time"]=>
        string(6) "7.30pm"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(3) {
        ["location"]=>
        string(7) "Venue A"
        ["name"]=>
        string(4) "Mark"
        ["time"]=>
        string(6) "8.00pm"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(8) "2nd June"
    ["events"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["location"]=>
        string(7) "Venue B"
        ["name"]=>
        string(4) "Fred"
        ["time"]=>
        string(6) "5.00pm"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["location"]=>
        string(7) "Venue C"
        ["name"]=>
        string(5) "Boris"
        ["time"]=>
        string(6) "6.00pm"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
        ["location"]=>
        string(7) "Venue A"
        ["name"]=>
        string(6) "Rupert"
        ["time"]=>
        string(6) "7.00pm"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(3) {
        ["location"]=>
        string(7) "Venue A"
        ["name"]=>
        string(5) "David"
        ["time"]=>
        string(6) "9.00pm"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I need to do is combine this so attendees at the same location are grouped together where another attendee in a different location doesn't break up the list. So the above array would be changed to this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(8) "1st June"
    ["events"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["location"]=>
        string(7) "Venue A"
        ["attendees"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(4) "Pete"
            ["time"]=>
            string(6) "4.00pm"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(2) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(4) "John"
            ["time"]=>
            string(6) "4.30pm"
          }
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["location"]=>
        string(7) "Venue B"
        ["attendees"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(5) "Chris"
            ["time"]=>
            string(6) "7.30pm"
          }
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["location"]=>
        string(7) "Venue A"
        ["attendees"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(4) "Mark"
            ["time"]=>
            string(6) "8.00pm"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(8) "2nd June"
    ["events"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["location"]=>
        string(7) "Venue B"
        ["attendees"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(4) "Fred"
            ["time"]=>
            string(6) "5.00pm"
          }
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["location"]=>
        string(7) "Venue C"
        ["attendees"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(5) "Boris"
            ["time"]=>
            string(6) "6.00pm"
          }
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["location"]=>
        string(7) "Venue A"
        ["attendees"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(6) "Rupert"
            ["time"]=>
            string(6) "7.00pm"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(2) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(5) "David"
            ["time"]=>
            string(6) "9.00pm"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So here's how I've figured out to do it juggling variables and stepping through the original array:

```
// $eventsArray holds the original array data a per the first example
$newArray = array();
foreach($eventsArray as $day) {
    $curLocation = '';
    $todaysEvents = array();
    $teKey = -1;
    foreach($day['events'] as $event) {
        if($curLocation==$event['location']) {
            $todaysEvents[$teKey]['attendees'][] = array(
                'name' => $event['name'],
                'time' => $event['time']
            );
        } else {
            $todaysEvents[] = array(
                'location' => $event['location'],
                'attendees' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => $event['name'],
                        'time' => $event['time']
                    )
                )
            );
            $teKey = $teKey + 1;
        }
        $curLocation=$event['location'];
    }
    $newArray[] = array(
        'date' => $day['date'],
        'events' => $todaysEvents
    );
}
```

And this works! So why am I asking a question on Stack? Because this feels awfully clunky and I'm not convinced there isn't a much more efficient way of doing it. I get the feeling I'm adding overhead here where it's not necessary.

Comment: Nothing wrong with nested loops for data matching. The `$teKeyis` a bit strange starting at `-1` ?, and you could do `foreach($eventsArray as $dayKey => $day) {` to track the index. Also i'd like to see `$todaysEvents[$teKey]['attendees']` defined as an array if it doesn't exist, you may be getting some supressed warnings.

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I'm starting at -1 is because the comparison to check if the venue matches happens after the counter is moved, so setting it one behind keeps it in sync. And the 'attendees' array has to exist by the time the locations match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative version using some PHP 7 (7.3+) features:

```
$resultEvents = [];

foreach ($events as ['date' => $date, 'events' => $dayEvents]) {
  $resultDayEvents = ['date' => $date, 'events' => []];

  foreach ($dayEvents as ['location' => $location, 'name' => $name, 'time' => $time]) {
    $attendee = ['name' => $name, 'time' => $time];
    if ($location === ($previousLocation ?? null)) {
      $resultDayEvents['events'][array_key_last($resultDayEvents['events'])]['attendees'][] = $attendee;
    } else {
      $resultDayEvents['events'][] = ['location' => $location, 'attendees' => [$attendee]];
    }
    $previousLocation = $location;
  }

  $resultEvents[] = $resultDayEvents;
}
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/bC4LK**

Answer (score 1):

You can use references like a cursor to keep track of the last event processed. Less effort to compare location and add attendees. But that comes with the complexity of getting rid of it properly.

Also, but a minor thing is to use strict comparisons... Can avoid some frustrating moments by being more predectible...

```php
// $eventsArray holds the original array data a per the first example
$newArray = array();
foreach($eventsArray as $day) {
    $todaysEvents = array();
    $curEvent = null;
    foreach($day['events'] as $event) {
        if($curEvent===null || $curEvent['location']!==$event['location']) {
            unset($curEvent);
            $curEvent = array(
                'location' => $event['location'],
                'attendees' => array()
            );
            $todaysEvents[] = &$curEvent;
        }

        $curEvent['attendees'][] = array(
            'name' => $event['name'],
            'time' => $event['time']
        );
    }
    unset($curEvent);

    $newArray[] = array(
        'date' => $day['date'],
        'events' => $todaysEvents
    );
}
```

Comment: This is useful, but I think on the last event it won't capture the attendee as it'll fall out of the loop and then unset the curEvent array. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: The unset only occurs when the last attende of the event has been added. To have a better understanding, you should consider the "$curEvent['attendees'][]" as "$todaysEvents[$lastKey]['attendees']" because most of the operations performed on "$curEvent" will be reflected immediately on the entry referenced in "$todaysEvents". So ... you're not supposed to miss one.